# How to fast insert 'pipe operator' in Kaggle?

Tags: r, kaggle, magrittr

It's my first time on Kaggle and I'm using the notebook but I've noticed that the pipe operator (`%>%` or `|>`) don't work with `ctrl + shift + m`, the Rstudio's shortcut pipe operator.

How can I do it? With my keyboard, it's inconvenient to insert manually the two operators.

Comment: I don't use the kaggle notebook, but searching for "kaggle notebook keyboard shortcuts" does not provide much hope that there are many R-specific shortcuts there, nor can I find a way to define custom shortcuts.